# Fundamental issue with backbone collections

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, models

Being trying to get my head around Backbone, and was working away fine until I hit the following snag which makes me think I'm going about this wrong.

In the following code, I have a model and a collection. The collection is called `bb.model.Settings` an a function called `changetheme` which gets a value. Now I have the value getting this far, but when I go to save this item, Do I need to pass it to the model. I'm trying to call the save function in the model but am wondering do I actually need to this, it keeps failing anyway. Should I just save the collection or what is best way to save this

```
bb.model.Setting = Backbone.Model.extend(_.extend({    
    defaults: {
        theme: 'e'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(self)
    },
    save: function() {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(self)
    },
}))


bb.model.Settings = Backbone.Collection.extend(_.extend({  
    model:  bb.model.Setting,
    localStorage: new Store("settingb"),

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(self)
    },
    changetheme: function(value) {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(self)
        this.remove
        this.model.save() 
    },
}))
```

Comment: Semicolons are mostly optional in JavaScript but leaving them out is a bad habit.

Comment: okay, will put semicolons in going forward.

Comment: Any thoughts on how i can save my item... nothing seems to work.

Comment: I did it like this, which worked but might not be the best way  changetheme: function(value) {
       var self = this
          _.bindAll(self)
          var item = new bb.model.Item({
           theme: value
           })
       self.add(item)
       item.save()  

      },

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out this fiddle, you had a couple of errors in your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8gDqb/1/

Here's the js portion, see the fiddle for full working example:

```
var bb = {};
bb.model={};

bb.model.Setting = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    defaults: {
        theme: 'e'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this
        //_.bindAll(self) // no longer necessary with backbone.js
    },
    save: function() {
        var self = this
        //_.bindAll(self) // no longer necessary with backbone.js
    },
});


bb.model.Settings = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model:  bb.model.Setting,
    //localStorage: new Store("settingb"),

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this
        //_.bindAll(self) // no longer necessary with backbone.js
    },
    changetheme: function(value) {
        var self = this
        _.bindAll(self)
        //this.remove
        //_.bindAll(self) // no longer necessary with backbone.js
    },
});
```

Also, just in case you're reading old howtos about backbone in the net, you don't need to bindAll anymore.  That hasn't been necessary for quite some time.